# Cookie value is null

Tags: c#, cookies

I'm trying to read the value of a cookie that I have set but it keeps coming back null. This is how I'm setting the cooking: -

```
string username = "Shazoo";
HttpCookie ck = new HttpCookie("mycookie");
ck.Expires.AddDays(30);
ck.Values.Add("username", username);
Response.Cookies.Add(ck);
```

And these are the ways that I've tried to read it: -

1. `username = Request.Cookies.Get("mycookie").Values.Get("username");`
2. `username = Request.Cookies["mycookie"]["username"];`
3. `ck = new HttpCookie("mycookie");
   username = ck["username"];`
4. `ck = Request.Cookies["mycookie"];
   username = ck["username"];`

The above ways all return a null value. I know that the cookie is definitely there as I can see it in the developer tools console

Comment: Can you provide some more context here? You add it to a response than try to get it from a request? I just can't seem to wrap my head around this.

Comment: Tried..! This code is working fine.

Comment: Just check about the `username` that you have taken in the code before it set in cookie

Answer (score 0):

Trying the same with Assigning some values to the variable, Just check this code which is working fine,

**Set the Cookie**

```
var username = "abcd0";
HttpCookie ck = new HttpCookie("mycookie");
ck.Expires.AddDays(30);
ck.Values.Add("username", username);
Response.Cookies.Add(ck);
```

**Get the cookie values**

These three is working fine...

```
string username = "";

username = Request.Cookies.Get("mycookie").Values.Get("username");

username = Request.Cookies["mycookie"]["username"];

ck = Request.Cookies["mycookie"];
username = ck["username"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("MyTestCookie");
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

// Set the cookie value.
myCookie.Value = now.ToString();
// Set the cookie expiration date.
myCookie.Expires = now.AddYears(50); // For a cookie to effectively never expire

// Add the cookie.
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);

Response.Write("<p> The cookie has been written.");
```